# Directive inside another directive with a single object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an object that looks like so:

```
RecruitingGroups 
{
   GroupName = "stuff",
   GroupTarge = 1,
   Rule =
   {
     Id = 1,
     Match = All,
     Tags = 
     {
       1,
       2,
     }
   }
}
```

My Angular is like so:

```
app.directive('creategroup', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '../../Content/templates/RecruitingGroups/CreateGroup.html',
        link: function (scope, el) {
            scope.groups = data.RecruitingGroups;

            scope.createGroup = function () {
                scope.groups.push({ id: scope.groups.length });
            }
        }
    }
});

app.directive('group', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: '../../Content/templates/RecruitingGroups/Group.html',
        link: function (scope, el) {
            scope.rules = [];
            scope.addRule = function () {
                scope.rules.push({ id: scope.rules.length });
            }
        }
    }
});

app.directive('rule', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: '../../Content/templates/RecruitingGroups/Rule.html',
        link: function (scope, el) {
            scope.tags = [];
            scope.addTag = function () {
                scope.tags.push({ id: scope.tags.length + 1 });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I am struggling for words here, but how do I make the rule object (which is a child of the group object) fall in the right place of the directive. Maybe showing a screen shot of the expected output would explain more...
[image: Groups]

Notice there are 2 groups in the picture each with a single rule in each one. Each rule then has a tag inside of it. That is the output I am shooting for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create scope arrays for rules and groups and use ng-repeat to repeat my directive tag as needed.

i.e.

```
<group ng-repeat="group in groups">
   <rule ng-repeat="rule in group.rules></rule>
</group>
```

where group is an array of objects where each object(group) has a property rules which is an array of objects(rule)

Comment: The only problem I have is when adding a rule (scope.addRules) the scope.rules.push() breaks of course. How can I bypass this error. I can't say scope.groups.rule.push() since its not available

Comment: so add Rule is inside of the group directive and each group needs to have a property rules which is an array of objects then inside your template you do something like ng-click="addRule(group)" pass the group object then in your controller you just access it in the function: $scope.addRule = function(group){ group.rules.push() }; also make sure rules is not an object of objects otherwise you'll need to do it differently group.rules[somekey] = someObject